# Pyplot / ArtistAnimation multiple subplots with animations

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, subfigure

I'm trying to plot multiple animations using pyplot / artistanimation. I want to plot them all at the same time but it seems to only plot the last matrix and the two other subplots are empty. 
A,B and C are quite large matrices that are created at the update_grids step (definitely working fine) - they are updated at every iteration. the final plot should hence be a plot of 3 subfigures with the animations (cellular automata grid)  showing simultaneous updates for all 3 matrices.

```
images = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
for a in range(t):
    A,B,C,AD,BD,CD,af,bf,cf = update_grids(A,B,C,AD,BD,CD,size,b)
    ax1 = plt.imshow(A,interpolation='nearest',cmap='binary')
    ax2 = plt.imshow(B,interpolation='nearest',cmap='binary')
    ax3 = plt.imshow(C,interpolation='nearest',cmap='binary')
    images.append([ax1,ax2,ax3])
    a_freq.append(af/(np.sum(A)+np.sum(B)+np.sum(C)))
    b_freq.append(bf/(np.sum(A)+np.sum(B)+np.sum(C)))
    c_freq.append(cf/(np.sum(A)+np.sum(B)+np.sum(C)))
ani = anm.ArtistAnimation(fig,images,interval=250,repeat=False,blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you want to plot an image to the `ax1` you need to call `ax1.imshow(...)`. Also, do not assign an image to the name of a an axes because otherwise you loose the axes handle.